# GTM web tracking jQuery().submit(function not working with AngularJS form

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-tag-manager

We want to use Google Tag Manager to track form submissions. When I add the jQuery script from GTM and test it, the script doesn't even fire - not even a "hello. I've stripped out the AngularJS {{expression}} values to protect our company property. I hope this is enough information.

```
<div id="login_signIn" class="">
  <form id="login_form" name="loginForm" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Sign In</legend>
      <label for="u_name" ng-class=""> Email address </label>
      <input name="u_name" id="u_name" type="email" maxlength="50" ng-model="" required ng-class="" />
      <label for="Password1" ng-class=""> Password </label>
      <input name="passwd" id="Password1" type="password" maxlength="50" ng-model="" required ng-class="" />
      <div class="login_forgot p-bottom clearfix"> <span class='loading f-left' ng-show=""> <img src="/images/loading.gif" width="48" height="47" alt="Loading" /> </span> <span class="f-right"><a href="/forgot-password/"><em>Forgot Password?</em></a></span> </div>
      <div class="form-error p-bottom clearfix" ng-show=''></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign In" name="new_submit_img" ng-click="" class="cliq-submit" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#login_form').submit(function(e){
            alert("hello");
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            window.dataLayer.push({
                'event' : 'formSubmissionSuccess',
                'formId' : 'login_form'
            }); 
        });
      </script>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: We're using jquery.min 1.12.4, jquery-migrate.min.js 1.4.1 and AngularJS v1.2.26

Comment: When I debug it, the breakpoints I set doesn't stop the page, it just submits the form and goes along to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article about different ways to go about adding the GTM script when the GTM script above doesn't work:

http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-abandonment-with-google-tag-manager/

Under the title: The base Custom HTML Tag I used this script above the GTM script block we place right after the opening body tag and it worked like a charm.:

```
    <script>
      (function() {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
          window.dataLayer.push({
            'event' : 'formSubmissionSuccess',
            'formId' : 'login_form'
          });
        });
      })();
    </script>
```